# Difference in Class Calling PHP

Tags: php, fuelphp

With learning fuelPHP, I am introduced on calling classes using scope resolution, or :: in sense. Typically, when we call a method in a class we do this ...

```
$myclass = new myclass();
$myclass->mymethod();
```

On fuel, methods are usually called in this manner ...

```
myclass::mymethod();
```

I was wondering if there are any difference between the two? Is the scope resolution is something of an update on 5.3 as well ... if not, which one is ideal, or when should I use these.

Thanks.

Comment: You should read this http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: The `::` operator has been around for a while actually :)

Answer (score 3):

The scope resolution operator is used to access either class constants like `::const`, static variables like `::$var` or call static methods like `::method()`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Static methods can be called without having an instance of the class they are defined in. They're defined in that class with the `static` keyword.

For example, one of CakePHP's static methods is defined like this:

```
class ClassRegistry {
    // ...
    public static function &getInstance() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

... which you can call like `ClassRegistry::getInstance()`.

Without the `static` keyword, you'd need an instance of the `ClassRegistry` class to call that function.

You can read more here, especially about why using `static` methods in your own code can sometimes be a bad idea: http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html

Comment: The first sentence doesn't make sense; `::` *is* the scope resolution operator after all :)

Comment: In fuelPHP I create functions without static on it in the MCV. Should I add static on it?

Comment: The arguments from the article "Static considered harmful" doesn't really apply to FuelPHP. In what they did, you actually can change the implementation, even with the static call.

Comment: @Jack - you are dismayingly correct, and I feel like a turkey. I've switched this thing over to a community wiki so you can have the honour of unretarding my sentence.

Comment: @Savageman - I linked to the "Static considered harmful" article as a warning against writing static methods in your own code, not as a critique against their use in existing code (or indeed just their appropriate use). I see my wording isn't clear, though. Will edit.

Comment: In FuelPHP, static methods are helper methods, either to replace "old_style" global functions, or to provide a factory pattern. In some causes, they are in interface to the default instance, just to prevent you from fetching the instance object first before you can call a method on it.

Session::set() === Session::instance()->set().

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how would `myclass::mymethod();` work, since I use such syntax only when I am calling a `STATIC` class.

`MyClass::DoSomething();`

would call a static method named DoSomething()

while

`$instance = new MyClass();`

`$instance->DoSomething();`

would call the instance method.

I have not tested it but I believe you will run into an error if you do `$instance::DoSomething()`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to understand why there is a static call and what it does behind the scene is to check this FuelPHP blog's entry: http://fuelphp.com/blog/2011/05/why-did-you-do-that

The obvious difference is that the first solution `$myObject->myMethod()` it's a dynamic call : you need an instance to execute `myMethod()`.

In the second solution, `MyClass::myMethod()` is a static call. The class acts as a sort of namespace where a function belong. You don't need an instance for that.